# How to get a data on the client side with javascript from the render express method?

Tags: express

I use to work with MVC javascript framework such as Backbone or Angular, i would like to fully use express and there is something i don't know how to do.

When i used javascript client framework, i made AJAX GET calls to get my entities from express with `res.send()`, but only with the express rendering engine, how to get the entity you send with `res.render('index', { User: { name: 'bob' }})` on the client side in your javascript code?

I tried on the client side to directly call:

```
<script>
console.log(JSON.stringify(User));
</script>
```

But i get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: User is not defined`

However, i can access the object in my html using `ejs`:

```
<h1><%= User.name %></h1>
```

I know how to get it in the html using the `ejs view engine`, but how to get it directly from the javascrit ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like client side rendering? Then RequireJS is the thing for you. res.send sends the data back to the client javascript framework and res.render renders a page or a template. Do let me know if you require something else.

Comment: Hi, i just want to get the datas i send from the server side on the client side (with javascript), i am not sure this is what requireJS does, if i understand its enable us to load modules on the client side

Comment: You are correct Ludo, requirejs first creates js files for the templates that you write and then you can call those modules directly from client side to render your pages.

Comment: To send data to the client side from the server, response.send or response.write can be used.

Comment: Ok, apparently i don't need to use any specific modules on the client side here, i just want to get back the `User` object, so i guess i have to use `res.send()`, but i also need to render my template, can't i do these both things at the same time ? Or do i need to render first the view then make an AJAX call to get the `User` object?

Comment: You can do it in the same res.render. You can have res.render('template name','user object');

Comment: in the script console.log try console.log(JSON.stringify(locals.User)); that might help

Comment: I get `locals is not defined` (sorry i should miss something...). I however am still able to get the object by calling `<%= User.name %>` in my html

Comment: Aaahh gotcha, res.render will render the template directly without passing the data first in javascript. Either you have to use ajax calls to nodejs servers and then recieve data in there success callback functions (at server res.send()) or there is an option that you described using <%=User.name %>

Answer (score 0):

Answering this much later, but I ran across this issue and had to work with it for quite a while before I got it, thought I would share for future visitors of this question.

Like V31 said earlier, `res.render` renders the template without passing the data first in JavaScript. The variables like `<%= User.name %>` only refer to their server-side definition as long as your EJS template is actually an EJS template -- which it stops being once it's been rendered as the page. As the Express docs say, `render` "returns the rendered HTML of a view." In other words, saying `console.log(User.name)` client-side is trying to access an object that only exists in the server.

You can get around this like this:

```
<script>
    console.log('<%= JSON.stringify(User) %>');
</script>
```

With the quotes required around the `<%= JSON.stringify(User) %>` because this result will be a string rather than a variable -- you don't want your `console.log` treating the entire stringified user data as a variable, you just want to log it.

Taking this concept further, this is how one would make variables you're passing into your render accessible to client-side JavaScript files as well. For example, say you have a `document.onLoad` function that requires a variable from the server to decide whether or not to make a particular DOM manipulation.

```
<script>
   const bob = '<%= User.name %>';
   const alice = '<%= User.bestfriend %>';
</script>
<script src='/javascripts/myscript.js'></script>
```

`myscript.js` now has access to `User.name` and `User.bestfriend` as they were defined in the server's `User` object, and can use that data client-side in whatever manner you see fit.

Comment: I came across this while trying to solve this issue. I need to get a single data item (string containing lat/lng) from the backend to client-side javascript. I can get the data to render, but I can't get it so I can use it. Could you elaborate more on where on how I would do this? Where are you placing `const bob = ...`, etc? The paragraph you have above the block of code doesn't match up in my mind. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sure. You'd put it somewhere in your views. Here's an example of how it looks in an EJS view:  https://github.com/jlr7245/healthify/blob/master/views/partials/todaynutrition.ejs#L23 (ignore the angry red highlighting)

The script section isn't "activated" until the view is actually sent out of the server and to the client in its rendered form. At that point, the variables `todaySodium`, etc. have no meaning to the browser, so we have to embed their values in the EJS before it gets sent over.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up pulling in jQuery and using AJAX, which is really overkill, but it worked. In the future, I'll try to play with your approach more. I gave it a roll, but since my views were already using PUG, and trying to use with EJS.....anyway, it seemed simpler to go the route I've had a teany bit of experience with.