# JQuery: Sending Multiple Data from Server via AJAX

Tags: jquery, express

I am currently obtaining `HTML` data format from the server via `AJAX`. The JQuery code looks like this, where the data obtained from server `result` is a bunch of `HTML`.

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/home",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(//some data sent...)
  }).done(function(result){
      //"result" is HTML data
      document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = result;
      //I would like to get another data from the server here.
  });
```

Apart from that `HTML`, I would also like to receive another data, which is just a number. How can I obtain both `HTML` and the number data all at once using `AJAX`? Here is the ExpressJS code:

**NodeJS/Express**

```
router.post("/home", function(req, res) {
    User.findById(id).exec(function(err, user){
        res.render("home", {user: user});
        //Do I need to add something here (like res.render), or modify the above res.render?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the number in your `res.render` thing also.

```
res.render("home", { user: user, number: number }
```

Then if you need that number in your client-side script, add something to that effect in your ejs.

```
<script>
  const myNumber = parseInt(<%= number %>)
</script>
```

More on doing that here: [How to get a data on the client side with javascript from the render express method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400876/how-to-get-a-data-on-the-client-side-with-javascript-from-the-render-express-met/42015384#42015384)

Basically, when the EJS template is created it's just stamping values into a file without knowing what the values mean. Then it gets turned into HTML in the browser, and the JS will run.

Answer (score 0):

Have the function return an object so you can return the html and number you value

```
[Data Contract]
public class returnData {
   [Data Member]
   public string HTML {get; set;}

   [Data Member]
   public string number {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how to modify the express.js code with your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used Express.js.  But I found this article that might help you figure it out.

http://www.primaryobjects.com/2012/11/11/reading-post-data-in-node-js-express-easy-manager-method/